# Closure gets lost while using dispatch group

Tags: swift, closures

Dispatch code not calling.When I call reLog() method it is not executing the code written in DispatchQueue.main.async block.

```
       func reLog() -> Bool {
            var isVerified = false
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
                    self.login({ () -> Void in
                        isVerified = true
                        group.leave()
                    }, fail: { (failureDict) -> Void in
                        group.leave()
                    })
                }
            group.wait() 
            return isVerified
        }


        func login(_ success : (()-> Void), fail : (()-> Void)){
             let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
             let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest){
                (data, response, error) -> Void in
                  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                       print("Testing")   // This closure not calling
                  })
             })
             task.resume()
        }
```

Now it 's my requirement to to this. I need to implement this because I need server response to continue the loop.

```
for i in strings {
     let isLogged = relog()
     if isLogged {
        print("Successful")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need  inside `login`

```
task.resume()
```

---

Replace

```
group.wait() 
return isVerified
```

with

```
group.notify(queue:.main) {
  completion(isVerified)
}
```

And

```
func reLog(completion:@escaping(Bool) -> ())
```

---

Edit

```
func reLog(completion:@escaping(Bool) -> ())
            var isVerified = false
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
                    self.login({ () -> Void in
                        isVerified = true
                        group.leave()
                    }, fail: { (failureDict) -> Void in
                        group.leave()
                    })
                }
        group.notify(queue:.main) {
          completion(isVerified)
        } 
 }
```

call

```
 reLog {  isVerified in
   print(isVerified)
 }
```

Comment: why you use `for i in strings {` check edit of how you should call it

Comment: I am trying this but the same thing is happening with me not calling main thread within the data task

Comment: using for i in strings { because I need server response to continue the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The closure is not called because you set the `delegate` of the `URLSession` to `self` which requires to adopt the protocol and implement the delegate methods.

Use the `init` method with `nil` delegate

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
```

And you are misusing `DispatchGroup` to make an asynchronous task synchronous. That's very bad practice.